# Необходим ли gzip в RestFull проекте?

Tags: node.js, nginx, gzip

Понимаю что делает gzip, но не понимаю как в плане расходуемых ресурсов. Выигрыш очевиден как мне кажется при отправке файлов(html/js/css/etc) размером более 500+Кбайт. Но если в сервисе идет отправка данных размером 1-20Кбайт? 75% ответов примерно 10Кбайт. Стоит ли в таком случае использовать сжатие gzip?

Думаю важным будет уточнить что сервис работает на node.js, возможно будет стоять за nginx. При использовании nginx думаю возложить на него обязанности по сжатию, но при условии, если gzip может дать (хоть и незначительное ускорение) при малых размерах файлов. Просто из за непонимания механизма gzip есть подозрение, что выигрыша не будет, а будет лишняя нагрузка на CPU (верно ли, что gzip нагружает только CPU?).

Upd. Статики нет, только выборка из БД.

Comment: Сжимать таки необязательно перед каждой отправкой, один раз сожми, семь раз отдай =)

Comment: В сжатии обычно выигрывают медленные каналы. Если имеются такие - то сжатие лучше включить.